# Why that code don't draw sprites C++ SFML

Tags: c++, textures, sprite, sfml

I wanted to draw sprites on screen having only information about it in my struct and next draw text on it

Information are good 
X and Y scale=1
Path is good and point to graphic 
position and rotation =0;

int free have a good number

But Text works 
so i don't know why Sprite don't

I tried commenting code with drawing and making text don't work

```cpp
struct ObjectInfo
{
    float Xpoz,Ypoz;
    std::string TexPath;
    float Xscale,Yscale;
    float Rotation;

};
ObjectInfo OI[1000];

int free;

void Draw()
{
    for(int i=0;i<free;i++)
    {
        sf::Texture t;
        t.loadFromFile(OI[i].TexPath);
        sf::Sprite s;
        s.setTexture(t);
        s.setPosition(OI[i].Xpoz,OI[i].Ypoz);
        s.setScale(OI[i].Xpoz,OI[i].Ypoz);
        s.setRotation(OI[i].Rotation);

        okno.draw(s);

        sf::Text text;
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setCharacterSize(48);
        text.setColor(sf::Color::Black);
        text.setPosition(s.getPosition());
        text.setString(IntToString(i));

        okno.draw(text);
    }
}
```

I expected that sprites and Text display
but only text display

Comment: `s.setScale(OI[i].Xpoz,OI[i].Ypoz);` why positions were used instead of scale values?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `s.setTexture(t)` sprite s remembers texture t by pointer/reference. So, when your code exit from for loop `sf::Texture t` is destroyed (C++ destroy scope variables when exiting some scope) and pointer/reference in sprite class points to deleted memory locations, which cause SFML to have error while drawing your sprites. The solution to this problem is the global array for textures which you use. I also recommend adding the global array for sf::Sprites, because it makes your code safer. Here is how it may be implemented:

```
//In the global scope
sf::Texture textures[1000];
sf::Sprite sprites[1000];
//void draw() new for loop
for(int i=0;i<free;i++)
{
    textures[i].loadFromFile(OI[i].texPath);
    sprites[i].setTexture(s);
    //Set other parameters
    okno.draw(s);
    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setCharacterSize(48);
    text.setColor(sf::Color::Black);
    text.setPosition(s.getPosition());
    text.setString(IntToString(i));

    okno.draw(text);
}
```

By the way, there are some more improvements to your code. Texture loading operation is a heavy operation, so if paths to textures are immutable, I will recommend you adding some method for loading them at once. Also, creating text class may be a heavy operation, so it is good to add global array of `sf::Text` classes you use

Comment: Global scopes aren't the perfect way to go. In my opinion using OOP would be best here. having a class for the set of objects and then methods for that class eg that draw function. Leaving variables / arrays in global state leaves program messy. Not a big change but worth it.